# Hyperledger Composer Playground on wrong version

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer

When I install Hyperledger Composer Playground using

npm install -g composer-playground

It install a version of Playground that says

Playground v0.16.3

When I attempt to connect to the blockchain it says with Composer Playground is says

Composer runtime (0.16.5) is not compatible with client (0.16.3)

How do I make the versions the same. I have uninstall and reinstalled everything multiple times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

that is unusual - did you do an `npm uninstall -g composer-playground` (global uninstall) first ? Because I just checked this in Linux 16.04 LTS and it comes up with the right version?

```
npm uninstall -g composer-playground

npm install -g composer-playground 

npm ls -g --depth==0 |grep playground
```

reveals composer-playground 0.16.5 after it successfully installs and from the last npm statement above. I suggest to try this sequence and let me know.

Comment: I reimaged my system and started from scratch. It's working now.